# iPhone - Catching an uiimageview touch events from a custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i would like to build a custom table view cell and put in him a imageview and when the user click the imageview to popup a view on the viewcontroller-and the view will know which cell the image was pressed.

thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `UITapGestureRecognizer` gesture to detect touches on any view inherited from `UIView`.

Use as below.....

Add Tap gesture `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `myImageView` view (type of `UIImageView`).

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *myTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureTapEvent:)];
myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myImageView addGestureRecognizer:myTapGesture];
[myTapGesture release];
```

Implement `gestureTapEvent:` method to receive the touch event.

```
-(void)gestureTapEvent:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture 
{

}
```

**UPDATED:**

you could access view with you attached the gesture using `view` property of [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) .

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view;
```

So your gestureTapEvent: method should be like as below .

```
-(void)gestureTapEvent:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture 
{
     UIImageView* myImageView = (UIImageView*)gesture.view ;
}
```

Comment: but how i will know which imageview was clicked in the tap method?

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple possibilities for that:

- Use UIGestureRecognizer to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your imageView (I would recommend this solution)
- Subclass UIImageView to override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` methods, etc.
- Add a UIButton (of type Custom, to avoid the frame of the button to be drawn) over your UIImageView

Example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:)];
[cell.yourImageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
[gestureRecognizer release];
```

---

*[EDIT]*

Then when you implement your `imageViewClicked` method, you can get the tapped ImageView using the `view` property of the GestureRecognizer. Starting from that, you can for example:

- use the tag of your imageView (if you affected it in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method) to retrieve the tag and do whatever you want with it (depending on what you affected it to, for example you may have set `imageView.tag = indexPath.row` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and get that indexPath row back then)
- Go thru the superviews of the imageView up to the UITableViewCell, then ask for its indexPath to get it back and do whatever you want with it.

Example:

```
-(void)imageViewClicked:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestRecognizer
{
    UIImageView* iv = (UIImageView*)gestRecognizer.view;
    NSInteger tag = iv.tag; // then do what you want with this

    // or get the cell by going up thru the superviews until you find it
    UIView* cellView = iv;
    while(cellView && ![cellView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        cellView = cellView.superview; // go up until you find a cell

    // Then get its indexPath
    UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)cellView;
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Comment: but how i will know which imageview was clicked in the tap method?

Comment: you have to keep track on indexPath.row

Comment: The `view` property of the UIGestureRecognizer (that is passed as a parameter to your `imageViewClicked:` selector) will give you access to the UIImageView. Then you can for example use the tag of your imageView to keep track of which model objet or indexPath is associated to it (if you set the tag when returning the cell) or get the parent UITableViewCell and ask for its indexPath. (I will update my answer to give the code)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UIImageView you can take custom UIButton and assign same image to button and you will get touchupInside event of that button. Just assign button.tag = indexpath.row so you can get which cell's Button pressed.

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender{
     UIButton *btnSelected = sender;
     switch(btnSelected.tag){
       case: 0
       ///Cell 0's Button Pressed. 
       break;
       ......
       ......
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

To add a touch event to a UIImageView use the following format in your .m

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *newTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(newTapMethod)];

[_imageButtonName setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[_imageButtonName addGestureRecognizer:newTap];
```

then create the newTapMethod (or what ever you name it)

```
-(void)newTapMethod{
//...
}
```

hope that helps.